# Qt TableView+Delegate+ProxyIndex+PersistenIndex - deleting rows with widgets

Tags: python, pyside2, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel, qitemdelegate

I'm trying to figure out how to code table with widgets with sorting/filtering possibility.
I use QItemDelegate, QAbstractTableModel, QTableView.

Already checked many threads on this topic which led me to code part of my app.

What I want to understand is how to properly delete rows to keep all these indexes and data coherent. At first I though I got it right, but playing with sorting and deleting more then few times shows very strange behavior for the column with button delete widget.

For example if I keep clicking button in the same table row (eg 5) these delete buttons simply shifts upword while first 3 column are updated correctly. Also some delete button are being duplicated.

Whole code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication( )


from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout ,QVBoxLayout,QGridLayout,QStackedLayout, QTableView 
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

# QHBoxLayout   Linear horizontal layout
# QVBoxLayout   Linear vertical layout
# QGridLayout   In indexable grid XxY
# QStackedLayout
def get_layout(ll):

    if ll not in ['grid','hbox','vbox','stack']:
        # print(ll)
        # print('wrong layout name')
        exit()
        
    ret_layout = QGridLayout()
    
    if ll=='hbox':
        ret_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    elif ll=='vbox':
        ret_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    elif ll=='stack':
        ret_layout = QStackedLayout()

    return ret_layout
    
    
    
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self, win_title='Default title', win_layout='grid',main_widget = QWidget()):
    
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle(win_title)
        self.layout_name=win_layout
        self.main_layout=get_layout(win_layout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1000,800)
         
        main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
         
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
 
    def addFrame(self,frame):
    
        if self.layout_name!='grid':
        
            if type(frame)==type([]):
                self.main_layout.addWidget(frame[-1])
            else:
                self.main_layout.addWidget(frame)
                
        else:
            self.main_layout.addWidget(frame[2],frame[0],frame[1])

            


import sys
import json
import PySide2
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt #, QFile, QIODevice


class ExampleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, index, parent=None):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.orig_index=index
        self.p_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        
        self.content_button = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.content_button)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0,0)
        
        self.delete_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("delete "+str(index.row()))
        
        self.delete_btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_clicked)
        lay.addWidget(self.delete_btn)
        self.content_button.move(x, 0)
        
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def delete_clicked(self):

        model = self.p_index.model() # QSortFilterProxyModel
        src_model=model.sourceModel()
        src_index=model.mapToSource(self.orig_index)
        rows_to_del=1
        
        zxc=src_model.removeRows(src_index.row(),rows_to_del,src_index, self.p_index )
        # self.deleteLater()
        # self.QtWidgets.~QWidget()
        
        

        
class CustomDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate): #QStyledItemDelegate

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super(CustomDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        
        if index.column()==3:
            return ExampleWidget(300, index, parent)
        
            

            
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel ): 

    def __init__(self, table=[], col_headers=[], row_headers=[], bg_color=None ):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.table =  table 
        self.col_headers=col_headers  
        self.row_headers=row_headers  
        self.bg_color=bg_color or QtGui.QColor('lightgrey')
        
    
    def itemFromIndex(self,index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
    
        rr=index.row()
        cc=index.column()
        return str ( self.table[rr][cc] ) 
        
        
    def removeRows(self,row, count, index, p_index):
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.beginRemoveRows(index,row,row)
        del self.table[row]
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        
        return True
        
        
    def data(self, index, role ):
    
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
    
        rr=index.row()
        cc=index.column()
        
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            vvalue = str ( self.table[rr][cc] ) 
            return vvalue #QtWidgets.QPushButton
        
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return self.bg_color
                
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.table)
        # return 5
        
    def columnCount(self, index):
        if len(self.table)>0:
            return len(self.table[0])
        return 0
        
        
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    
        if section<0:
            return
    
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                if len(self.col_headers)>section:
                    return str(self.col_headers[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                if len(self.row_headers)>section:
                    return str(self.row_headers[section])
        
        
        
        
class TableView( QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self,params={}):
        super(TableView, self).__init__( )
        
        self.model = TableModel()
        
        self.sorting_proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.sorting_proxy.setSourceModel( self.model)
        self.setModel(self.sorting_proxy)       
        
        self.delegate=CustomDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
        
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        
        tmp_header_bg_color='lightgrey'
        if 'header_bg_color' in params:
            tmp_header_bg_color=params['header_bg_color']
            
        tmp_style="""QWidget  { background-color:%s; border:none; }
                    QHeaderView::section { background-color:%s; border:none; }
                    QTableCornerButton::section { background-color:%s; border:none; }
                    """ % (tmp_header_bg_color,tmp_header_bg_color,tmp_header_bg_color)
            
        self.setStyleSheet(tmp_style)
        
        if len(params)>0:
            if 'show_grid' in params:
                self.setShowGrid(params['show_grid'])
            if 'auto_resize':
                self.auto_resize=True
            

            
    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onClick(self, ix):
        # it = self.model.itemFromIndex(ix)
        it=self.sorting_proxy.data(ix)
        if hasattr(it,'data'):
            print(it.data())            
        else:
            print(it)
                
            
    def sortByCol(self,cc,dir='asc'):
        if dir=='asc':
            self.sortByColumn(cc, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        else:
            self.sortByColumn(cc, Qt.DescendingOrder)
            
            
            
            
            
    def setdata(self,data_list,col_headers=[],row_headers=[]):

        self.model.table=data_list
        self.model.col_headers=col_headers
        self.model.row_headers=row_headers
        
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
        
        if hasattr(self,'auto_resize'):
            self.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.resizeRowsToContents()

            

            

data_list = [
        ('ACETIC ACID', 117.9, 16.7, 1.049),
        ('ACETIC ANHYDRIDE', 140.1, -73.1, 1.087),
        ('ACETONE', 56.3, -94.7, 0.791),
        ('ACETONITRILE', 81.6, -43.8, 0.786),
        ('ANISOLE', 154.2, -37.0, 0.995),
        ('BENZYL ALCOHOL', 205.4, -15.3, 1.045),
        ('BENZYL BENZOATE', 323.5, 19.4, 1.112),
        ('BUTYL ALCOHOL NORMAL', 117.7, -88.6, 0.81),
        ('BUTYL ALCOHOL SEC', 99.6, -114.7, 0.805),
        ('BUTYL ALCOHOL TERTIARY', 82.2, 25.5, 0.786),
        ('CHLOROBENZENE', 131.7, -45.6, 1.111),
        ('CYCLOHEXANE', 80.7, 6.6, 0.779),
        ('CYCLOHEXANOL', 161.1, 25.1, 0.971),
        ('CYCLOHEXANONE', 155.2, -47.0, 0.947),
        ('DICHLOROETHANE 1 2', 83.5, -35.7, 1.246),
        ('DICHLOROMETHANE', 39.8, -95.1, 1.325),
        ('DIETHYL ETHER', 34.5, -116.2, 0.715),
        ('DIMETHYLACETAMIDE', 166.1, -20.0, 0.937),
        ('DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE', 153.3, -60.4, 0.944),
        ('DIMETHYLSULFOXIDE', 189.4, 18.5, 1.102),
        ('DIOXANE 1 4', 101.3, 11.8, 1.034),
        ('DIPHENYL ETHER', 258.3, 26.9, 1.066),
        ('ETHYL ACETATE', 77.1, -83.9, 0.902),
        ('ETHYL ALCOHOL', 78.3, -114.1, 0.789),
        ('ETHYL DIGLYME', 188.2, -45.0, 0.906),
        ('ETHYLENE CARBONATE', 248.3, 36.4, 1.321),
        ('ETHYLENE GLYCOL', 197.3, -13.2, 1.114),
        ('FORMIC ACID', 100.6, 8.3, 1.22),
        ('HEPTANE', 98.4, -90.6, 0.684),
        ('HEXAMETHYL PHOSPHORAMIDE', 233.2, 7.2, 1.027),
        ('HEXANE', 68.7, -95.3, 0.659),
        ('ISO OCTANE', 99.2, -107.4, 0.692),
        ('ISOPROPYL ACETATE', 88.6, -73.4, 0.872),
        ('ISOPROPYL ALCOHOL', 82.3, -88.0, 0.785),
        ('METHYL ALCOHOL', 64.7, -97.7, 0.791),
        ('METHYL ETHYLKETONE', 79.6, -86.7, 0.805),
        ('METHYL ISOBUTYL KETONE', 116.5, -84.0, 0.798),
        ('METHYL T-BUTYL ETHER', 55.5, -10.0, 0.74),
        ('METHYLPYRROLIDINONE N', 203.2, -23.5, 1.027),
        ('MORPHOLINE', 128.9, -3.1, 1.0),
        ('NITROBENZENE', 210.8, 5.7, 1.208),
        ('NITROMETHANE', 101.2, -28.5, 1.131),
        ('PENTANE', 36.1, ' -129.7', 0.626),
        ('PHENOL', 181.8, 40.9, 1.066),
        ('PROPANENITRILE', 97.1, -92.8, 0.782),
        ('PROPIONIC ACID', 141.1, -20.7, 0.993),
        ('PROPIONITRILE', 97.4, -92.8, 0.782),
        ('PROPYLENE GLYCOL', 187.6, -60.1, 1.04),
        ('PYRIDINE', 115.4, -41.6, 0.978),
        ('SULFOLANE', 287.3, 28.5, 1.262),
        ('TETRAHYDROFURAN', 66.2, -108.5, 0.887),
        ('TOLUENE', 110.6, -94.9, 0.867),
        ('TRIETHYL PHOSPHATE', 215.4, -56.4, 1.072),
        ('TRIETHYLAMINE', 89.5, -114.7, 0.726),
        ('TRIFLUOROACETIC ACID', 71.8, -15.3, 1.489),
        ('WATER', 100.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        ('XYLENES', 139.1, -47.8, 0.86)
        ]

tmpheaders=['a','b','c']

mw = MainWindow(win_layout='hbox' )

ff=TableView(params={'show_grid':False,'auto_resize':1 })
mw.addFrame(ff)
ff.setdata(data_list,tmpheaders)

mw.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a method that removes a row:

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    def removeRow(self, row):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row)
        del self.table[row]
        self.endRemoveRows()
```

And then map the row in the sourceModel:

```
class ExampleWidget(QWidget):
    # ...

    @Slot()
    def delete_clicked(self):
        index = QModelIndex(self.p_index)
        model = index.model()
        source_index = model.mapToSource(index)
        source_model = source_index.model()
        source_model.removeRow(source_index.row())
```

Comment: That is what I do have in the code above: removeRows(self,row, count, index, p_index) and  delete_clicked(self). But it works ok only for normal columns. Column with the button gets messed up after few deletes.

Comment: The problem is not that the method wasn't implemented, but that the wrong *parent* index was given as argument of `beginRemoveRows()`.

Comment: @kkonrad My code does not look like yours, analyze well please, on the other hand, have you tested my solution?

Comment: @kkonrad In addition to what @musicamante indicates, the other error is that the row is obtained from the QModelIndex(`self.orig_index`) that no one guarantees to be updated, for example the item from row 10 when removing row 1 does not change to row 9, to avoid that problem I use the QPersistenModelIndex directly.

Comment: I believe the parent index is correct and deleting itself too, because correct row is deleted each time (also after sorting). It's just the last column with widget that somehow fails. I double checked if suggested solution changes sth but it works the same to me (needed to add self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit() and self.layoutChanged.emit() because without it does not work well)

Comment: @kkonrad I don't understand you, with my solution it no longer generates a segmentation fault since I use the correct values unlike your code, does my solution work for you or not? Your comment above is confusing

Comment: @kkonrad I have added the complete code since I have also corrected other errors in your code.

Comment: Just tried exact copy of your code. There is no seg fault, and works better, but buttons in last column are still messed up after few deletes sort/ deletes. For example I see multiple "delete 24" buttons appear.

Comment: @kkonrad I think I understand what you mean, but I have a question: For example, let's say we have 4 rows and according to your logic there should be buttons with text "delete 0", "delete 1", "delete 2" and "delete3". If the "delete 1" button is pressed then should the texts of the other buttons be modified or should it be maintained? this is the button text must be "delete 0", "delete 1" and "delete 2" OR it must be "delete 0", "delete 2" and "delete3".

Comment: Ok it seems it's my thinking error at this point it seems solved :) I put there numbers while debuging to see how it behaves to try see if indexes were correct. I felt these values should be unique to prove nothing is messed up. But since there is no seg fault it seems correct. Thanks a lot!!! Now need to analize to understand it better.